# I want to retrieve all clients from Entity Framework but it returns 0 although i have records in the table

Tags: entity-framework, linq

My problem is as follows:

in ApplicationDbContext i have a DbSet Clients, in the dbo table i have 5 records. When i try to do some linQ query it retrieves 0 records although i have 5 records. I think I`m missing some IEnumerable at a class or something?

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Carer> Carers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}


    public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int IdClient { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FullAdress { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

}



    var xx = _Context.Clients; // this returns 0 records
```